# How can I allocate data array to opencv Mat::data

Tags: opencv, opencl, mat

I want to allocate any array to Mat::data area.

So, I use this Mat function.

```
Mat (int rows, int cols, int type, void *data, size_t step=AUTO_STEP)
```

like below.

```
unsigned char arr[640*480*3];
Mat ass = Mat(640, 480, CV_8UC3, arr);
```

After above declaration, ass.data address and arr address is same. So, it is shared each element.

But when I read a frame from webcam(Videocapture::read) or read a image(imread()) after above declaration,

```
ass = imread("qq.jpg"); or cap.read(ass);
```

ass.data address is changed to other address. Of course each element isn't shared.

In this situation, I want to allocate data array to Mat::data and continually share each element after I read a frame.

How can i do?

Ultimately, I want to capture a frame from webcam and deal with the frame in opencl.

Now, Opencv 3.0 support opencl framework with "UMat" class.

But I know Umat doesn't support a direct access to each element and it need to copy process.

So, I attempt to allocate Mat::data array to CPU-GPU shared buffer area and capture a frame to the shared buffer directly.
(Refer to [here](http://malideveloper.arm.com/downloads/deved/tutorial/SDK/opencl/memory_buffers_tutorial.html))

If so, it does not have to copy array, and it is more efficient i think.

If anyone has more efficient idea, please give me some advice!

Thanks!

Comment: you can not do what you want.. when uploading an image to gpu, you can not address it using CPU

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Hmm..... thanks for your reply. For using shared memory efficiently, maybe, I should use another method like memcpy() function. Thanks.